# On android, when I set the Text of a TextView dynamically it doesn't change

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am new to the android platform so I know I am just missing something by here is what I have

```
<!-- activity_main -->
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.example_app.MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/mainFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.example.example_app.MainFragment"
     />

</FrameLayout>
```

Then I created a fragment called MainFragment.java.

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {
    public TextView displayTextView;
    public MainFragment() { }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        this.displayTextView = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.displayTextView);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

I add the fragment in the OnCreate function in the activity and it seems to be adding everything okay but when I click on the button nothing happens, I logged the function to see its being called but setting the textview doesn't do anything. What am I doing wrong?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.example_app.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/button10"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="34dp"
        android:text="10%"
        android:layout_below="@id/amountEditText"
        android:background="@drawable/pct_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="doSomething"
     />

    <TextView 
        android:text="Blah Blah Blah"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:id="@+id/displayTextView" 
    ></TextView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is the click Event in the MainActivity.java

```
public void doSomething(View v) {
    this.mainFragment.displayTextView.setText("Nothing to set for some reason!");
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        // 
        this.mainFragment = (MainFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mainFragment);
        mainFragment = new MainFragment();

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(mainFragment, "mainFragment").commit();

    }
}
```

Comment: Just a hunch... but did you set a onClickListener on that button?

Comment: I set onClick in the fragments buttons XML

Comment: Need to see more of the MainActivity where mainFragment is set.

Comment: I just updated adding the oncreate function from the main activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declaring onClick-Listeners via XML is possible if you work with Activities. According to the Google API, however, you need to declare OnClickListeners programmatically if you use Fragments.

> [...] You can also declare the click event handler programmatically rather than in an XML layout. This might be necessary if you instantiate the Button at runtime or you need to declare the click behavior in a Fragment subclass.

Source: 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button.html

So you may want to use this instead:

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {
public TextView displayTextView;
public Button yourButton;
public MainFragment() { }

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    this.displayTextView = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.displayTextView);
    yourButton = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.button10);
    yourButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
              displayTextView.setText("Nothing to set for some reason!");
         }
    });

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Comment: So even if the event is firing? Because I can set break points an it reaches the breakpoints.

Comment: That is really interesting. That onClick does certainly fire and you can even route that event all the way down to the fragment. Even using breakpoints, the debugger told me that the values of the TextView had changed, but the View did not update the TextView after that. I suspect you need to add a handler or a AsyncTask to update the UI in the fragment which would make it more cumbersome. My solution, however, is short and works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the way you try to execute the button click. From your question i understand that `Button and TextView` is in `Fragment` view. So do why are Trying to access it in activity ?? It is wrong, then there is no point of using Fragments. Also this will lead to many serious issues later .

Fragments are Reusable components so all the functionalities of a fragment must stay inside the Fragment Class

Change Fragment code :

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {
    public TextView displayTextView;
    public Button yourButton;
    public MainFragment() { }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        this.displayTextView = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.displayTextView);
        yourButton = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.button10);
        //Setting click listener for button in fragment 
        yourButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
        displayTextView.setText("Nothing to set for some reason!");
         }
    });
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

and remove  `android:onClick="doSomething"` from XML

Comment: But what if I have many buttons that are calling the same function, it seems like it would be easier to have them pointing to the some function in the XML rather than create the View.OnClickListener() over and over? And thank you for clarifying handle the logic in the fragment instead of the activity. I come from iOS which followings MVC, android doesn't.

Comment: @JasonFoster How about declaring only one OnClickListener and set all your buttons to that OnClickListener rather than creating View.OnClickListener all over again ?

Comment: @JasonFoster if so many buttons are calling same function what is the problem?? you can create a function and call it in so many button clicks